# How to sanitize user input in Deno?

Tags: sanitize, deno

I don't know much about security when it comes to Backend-JavaScript.

The only way I can imagine sanitizing the input is to use regex and replace all the unwanted characters, or split the whole string and filter/map the unwanted characters out, then join back together.

I'm also using the Oak module for Deno.

Comment: There are multiple type of attack, which attack u want to prevent. One module cant prevent all attacks. You can check helmet npm module for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out this https://deno.land/x/html_entities
According to lib documentation:

**HTML validity and XSS attack prevention you can achieve from XmlEntities module.**

```
import { XmlEntities } from "https://deno.land/x/html_entities@v1.0/mod.js";

XmlEntities.encode('<>"\'&©®'); // &lt;&gt;&quot;&apos;&amp;©®
XmlEntities.encodeNonUTF('<>"\'&©®'); // &lt;&gt;&quot;&apos;&amp;&#169;&#174;
XmlEntities.encodeNonASCII('<>"\'&©®'); // <>"\'&©®
XmlEntities.decode('&lt;&gt;&quot;&apos;&amp;&copy;&reg;&#8710;'); // <>"'&&copy;&reg;∆
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reuse the `sanitize` npm package:

```
npm i -g sanitize
```

And then you can use it like:

```
import { createRequire } from "https://deno.land/std/node/module.ts";

const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const sanitizer = require("sanitizer");

name = sanitizer.value(name, "string");
surname = sanitizer.value(surname, "string");
```

or you can replace this library with another sanitization library
and you run your deno script with: `deno run --allow-read --unstable script.ts`